# UIImageView Tap Gesture not recognizing. User interaction is Enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a container view as an input accessory view and within that, I've added a simple UIImageView with an upload image. I tried adding a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the image view but it doesn't seem to trigger the event given. User interaction is enabled.

Here is the code:

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        containerView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        containerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let chooseImage = UIImageView()
        chooseImage.image = UIImage(named: "upload_image_icon")
        chooseImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(chooseImage)


        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: #selector(handleChatImage))
        chooseImage.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        chooseImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        chooseImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

        chooseImage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        chooseImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        chooseImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        chooseImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true

        send.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
        send.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        containerView.addSubview(send)
        send.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        send.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        send.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        send.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        containerView.addSubview(self.inputTextField)
        self.inputTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: chooseImage.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        self.inputTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.inputTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: send.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.inputTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        divide.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        divide.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(divide)
        divide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        divide.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        divide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        divide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

        send.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendMessage), for: .touchUpInside)

        return containerView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target is `nil`  (  target is the object where `UITapGestureRecognizer` will look for the selector method in )

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: #selector(handleChatImage))
```

should be `self`

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleChatImage))
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude. I wouldn't have caught that mistake.